# Open GPUView trace on Different PC/OS

Tags: trace

I've taken a GPUView trace on one machine running Windows 10 but want to analyze the trace on a different machine running Windows 7. When I try to open the trace file, merged.etl, using GPUView I see the message:

> This etl file has data that was captured on a version of the OS that is different from the current OS. The data may not be displayed correctly or expose other side effects in GPUView.
>
> Would you like to continue loading this file anyway?

If I choose to open the trace anyway GPUView opens but there is nothing to view.

I know I should be able to view traces this way but I don't know the magic sauce to make it work. Does anyone know it?

As a last ditch effort, after finding nothing for this error online, I tried pointing GPUView to a folder containing symbols from the OS the trace was captured but this doesn't have any effect.

Thank you,
Lawrence F.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered this was happening due to using different GPUView versions on the two machines in question. I thought I had used the same version but it turns out I had serveral. I removed all the old version and installed the Windows 10 SDK on each machine (includes GPUView). This allowed me to view the trace on the Windows 7 host